# Black and Decker 18V Battery

Tags: tools

I put my 18V Black and Decker Battery on the charger yesterday and the red light is still blinking. Is this normal?

Comment: Please provide more information: how old is the battery, what is the model number (so we can identify chemistry -- nicad, lithium ion, other), how long has it been since the last charge, was it "empty" after the last time you used it or did you recharge it then, do you have any other batteries to try on the charger, is the battery getting warm to the touch while on the charger, did you put it on the charger particularly hot/cold?

Comment: I agree with the questions in the previous comment, but it's also true that most batteries, even Lithium ion, can only take so many charge cycles, especially if they're deep discharge cycles where you run the battery all the way down then recharge it. But then technologies like NiCad (Nickel/Cadmium) are really susceptible to a memory effect where if you only partially discharge them before recharging, they'll only provide power for a short time before they MUST be recharged. Can you buy a new battery? It might just be worn out. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Two things. The battery is no longer charging or the battery charger no longer meters output from the charger circuit for a match with the battery voltage.
If you can borrow a charger you can check the battery charging capability. If not start with a new battery.